# Copy contents of Git repository to OneDrive for Business

Tags: git, office365, azure-devops, onedrive

My team is preparing to begin using version control with Git, maintaining remote repositories on Visual Studio Team Services.  Rather than one or two large projects, we have hundreds of small ones -- scripts dependent on a third party environment, not independently buildable -- and thus expect to have hundreds of repos.

Only 25% of our company does programming work, but I do have non-programmer colleagues who will need occasional access to these files.  I would like to be able to set up something like a trigger that fires whenever a commit is pushed to the master branch, copying all of the files (or at least changed files) from the repo to a OneDrive for Business folder.  This way, I could give my colleagues access to the files without having to purchase VSTS licenses for everyone.

However, I haven't found a way to do this. I'm still fairly new to Git myself, and it looks like it might be possible to set up a bare repository in ODFB and use a Git hook to copy the files.  But it seems like this could only happen locally (meaning I would have to pull the repo -- again, we will likely have hundreds of repos).  If I have to manually intervene to make this happen, it's probably not workable.

*Leaving aside the question of whether or not it's a good idea*, is there any way to set up this automation directly from VSTS?

Comment: Do **not** store a repository in OneDrive unless it is a pure one-way communication channel and even then I would be hesitant. Do not push and fetch from multiple computers against such a repository. At **most** you can push to it from one computer and fetch from it from multiple others.

Comment: I don't want to maintain a Git repository on OneDrive.  I want to automate the copying of files *from* a repository to a folder in OneDrive.

Comment: If you use the Continuous Integration functionality for builds, you could deploy the source as part of that.

Answer (score 0):

One option you could look into is to use a script to pull automatically from git when changes are pushed (i.e. https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-auto-pull). This should give you a directory which always have the up to date files in it. Sync this folder with your onedrive (without the repository) and you should be good to go.

Please note that this is a bit of a hack and not the recommended way to approach this type of problem, but we all bodge from time to time.

Comment: Also note that you do not need visual studio to get files from git, there is git for windows, which is free and lets you do everything that VS lets you do with git, and a lot more.